# Outlet drop from 3 way Switch that doesn't have incoming power

Tags: switch, receptacle, multiway-switch

I have a light in my kitchen with three-way switches. Power comes into the first switch and leaves with a red traveler wire. Black white and red wires come into the second three-way switch. I want to drop an outlet for the second three-way switch. I do *not* need to have both switches remain active. I don't need the second switch at all. I have pictures of the first and second switch, but these are after I unwired and rewired them when my first attempt didn't work, I'm not sure I rewired them back correctly, in fact I'm sure I didn't because the second switch is not functioning. [[image: First switchsecond switch]

Comment: With a pair of three way switches, one of the switches has constant power coming to it, and the other switch sends power to the light.  Do you you know which switch you are "operating" on here?  Also, you might not want both switches, but code may require that they both work, if that's something you're worried about.

Comment: Also look at some three way wiring diagrams.  Each switch has a black screw for the "common" wire that will be power coming in or power going to a light, and two brass screws for "travelers" that go directly from switch to switch.  If you mix up the common and travelers, there are a variety of symptoms, and one switch not doing anything is one symptom.

Comment: Thank you. I'm pretty sure I'm working off the one that doesn't have constant power, I sometimes get a reading from it and sometimes not

Answer (score 4):

### Can't get a receptacle off that circuit

Sorry. Kitchen receptacles need to be on 20A circuits, and need to serve *only* receptacles.  Further, the circuit must serve receptacles only in the kitchen, dining and pantry areas.  (they can also serve the receptacle that powers a gas range, or a wall clock, but no other loads).

Tapping a kitchen receptacle off a light circuit is Right Out.

### In some cases, a switch there may be required

Depending on the building codes and the paths into the room, a switch there may be required so the lights can be turned on.  I couldn't speculate further without knowing more about the room layout.

### To roll that back to dual 3-ways, note how 3-way circuits work.

Your misconception is that there is only 1 traveler. Actually, there are two.  Here's a wiring diagram for 3-ways that I think is closest to yours (although the wire colors have been colored to depict *function*, your wires are not!)

[image]

The most important note is that the travelers go on the brass colored screws, and travelers are always in the same cable.  Since no traveler is white, I gather white is handling neutral, hence this diagram being a fit.